# Plotting ROC curve in cross validation using Matlab perfcurve

Tags: matlab, plot, classification, cross-validation, roc

I have the following code for a binary classifying using SVM, and 10 cross-validation,

Update: found the solution, See notes below

```
k=10;
cp = classperf(lables); 
cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', lables, k);   
 for i = 1:k                                 
  testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                %# get indices of test instances
  trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     %# get indices training instances


   svmModel = fitcsvm(data_features(trainIdx,:), lables(trainIdx), 
   'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','RBF','KernelScale','auto');

  [label,score] = predict(svmModel, data_features(testIdx,:));
  cp = classperf(cp, pred, testIdx);
  cumulative_score= [cumulative_score; score];
  label1 = [label1; label];

end
acc= cp.CorrectRate;
conf= cp.CountingMatrix;
```

I want to Plot the ROC curve using the  `perfcurve` function  in Matlab, However, the input 'score' changes each fold and can't be used outside the k-fold loop.

`[X,Y] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass)`

Any suggestion on how to plot a ROC in such case?
NOTE: [Solved] above by adding `cumulative_score= [cumulative_score; score];` inside the loop, and use it as an input to `perfcurve`

Answer (score 0):

By adding `cumulative_score= [cumulative_score; score];` inside the loop, and use it as an input to `perfcurve`